# Magento 2 Change Title Page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I need help to change the page title, the page is order details, I need to leave the page title dynamic, for each order to have its own, instead of showing increment id, I will show another attribute

I can change the title, but it always stays the same, as I did it by xml

my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
           <action method="setPageTitle">
              <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Custom Title</argument>
           </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        
    </body>
</page>
```

how do I change this via controller, or observer, to be dynamic?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in your **Block** file, open relevant block file and use this code:

```
$this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set("Your custom dynamic title");
```

where `$this->pageConfig` is the instance of `\Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config`

You can use this code in `__consturct` function or `_prepareLayout` function

Hope this will help you.